# Getting distinct values from Resultset

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, teradata

I have the following table Employee and records as follows:

```
Eid      Ename     Phone
------------------------     
 1         A        043
 1         A        067
 2         B        073
 2         B        072
 3         C        753 
 3         C        464
```

What I've got so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Eid ASC) AS rownum,
               Eid,
               Ename,
               Phone
        FROM   Employee
        WHERE  Eid IN(SELECT DISTINCT(Eid)
                      FROM   Employee
                      GROUP  BY Eid)) AS RESULTSET
WHERE  rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

Actually the inner query is returning the `distinct` results but it is not reflected when I am getting the result in final `RESULTSET`.

Please advise on how to get the distinct RESULTSET. My output should return like below:

```
Eid      Ename     Phone
------------------------     
 1         A         043
 2         B         073
 3         C         753
```

Comment: What is the rule for getting `043` rather than `067` as the `Phone` for `Eid`? If it's "because that's the first one", you're going to need to think about your design, because records in a SQL table *don't* have any built-in ordering.

Comment: Assuming that even the phone numbers are also same, also in the output I need the rownum column as well which I need to get from the resultset.

Comment: You need to fetch alternate rows?

Comment: Could you update your sample data to reflect that then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is much more complicated. Try simplifying it by using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Eid, a.Ename, c.Phone
FROM   EMPLOYEE a
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT  TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by Ename ORDER BY Eid ASC) AS RowNo,
          b.Eid, b.Phone
  FROM    EMPLOYEE b
  WHERE   a.EID = b.eid 
  ORDER BY RowNo ASC                         -- you can change this to DESC also
) c
```

The reason why I added `DISTINCT` is because you are joining the table with itself.

Another simplier version

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Eid, a.Ename, c.Phone
FROM   EMPLOYEE a
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT  TOP 1 b.Eid, b.Phone
  FROM    EMPLOYEE b
  WHERE   a.EID = b.eid 
) c
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5005d/21)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `QUALIFY` clause you can specify which range of Row_Number values you wish to return. The `QUALIFY` clause is to window aggregate functions what the `HAVING` clause is to non-window aggregate functions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       e1.eid
     , e1.ename
     , e1.ephone
--     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e1.eid ORDER BY e1.eid) AS RowNum_
FROM emp e1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e1.eid ORDER BY e1.eid) = 1
```

If you are including `RowNum_` in the result set then you can reference it in the `QUALIFY` instead of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window aggregate again.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhm Im not sure  how you want this query but somehow I based this in your expected output

Code:

```
select    Eid,Ename,Phone 
from      (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Eid ASC) AS rownum,
                  Eid,
                  Ename,
                  Phone 
           from Employee 
           where Eid in (select distinct(Eid) 
                         from Employee  )
         ) AS RESULTSET
Where rownum %2<>0
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d39a5/13)

Comment: Table is -                                                                Eid      Ename     Phone
------------------------     
 1         A        043
 1         A        043
 2         B        073
 2         B        073
 3         C        753 
 3         C       753                                              and the expected output should be -                                                            rownum  Eid      Ename     Phone
------------------------     
   1      1        A         043
   2      1        B         073
   3      1        C         753

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition by ename ORDER BY Eid ASC) AS rownum, 
               Eid, 
               Ename, 
               Phone 
        FROM   Employeee
        WHERE  Eid IN(SELECT DISTINCT(Eid) 
                      FROM   Employeee
                      GROUP  BY Eid)) AS RESULTSET 
WHERE  rownum =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select Eid,Ename,Phone from 
 (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Ename order by eid) as rn from emp) a
 where rn=1
```